# How to add a delay to code in C++.

Tags: c++, delay

I want to add a delay so that one line will run and then after a short delay the second one will run. I'm fairly new to C++ so I'm not sure how I would do this whatsoever. So ideally, in the code below it would print "Loading..." and wait at least 1-2 seconds and then print "Loading..." again. Currently it prints both instantaneously instead of waiting.

```
cout << "Loading..." << endl;
// The delay would be between these two lines. 
cout << "Loading..." << endl;
```

Comment: you forgot to mention the OS. On linux you can use the unistd function: `sleep(2)`?

Comment: which version of C++? I rather use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2))`...

Comment: I'm using C++11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in c++ 11 you can use this thread and crono to do it:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
...
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
```

Comment: Nice, clean, and standard.  But you need to add `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` before you can use the chrono literals.

Answer (score 1):

to simulate a 'work-in-progress report', you might consider:

```
// start thread to do some work
m_thread = std::thread( work, std::ref(*this)); 

// work-in-progress report
std::cout << "\n\n  ... " << std::flush;
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)  // for 10 seconds
{
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); // 
   std::cout << (9-i) << '_' << std::flush; // count-down
}

m_work = false; // command thread to end
m_thread.join(); // wait for it to end
```

With output:

> ... 9_8_7_6_5_4_3_2_1_0_
>
> work abandoned after 10,175,240 us

Overview: The method 'work' did not 'finish', but received the command to abandon operation and exit at timeout.  (a successful test)

The code uses chrono and chrono_literals.

Comment: During "work-in-progress", this snippet outputs a countdown (to cout) while letting m_thread run full blast.  m_thread must test the bool m_work periodically during operation.  Setting m_work to fals shuts down m_thread after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In windons OS

```
#include <windows.h>
Sleep( sometime_in_millisecs );   // note uppercase S
```

In Unix base OS

```
#include <unistd.h>
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

#include <unistd.h>
int usleep(useconds_t usec); // Note usleep - suspend execution for microsecond intervals
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the `sleep(unsigned int seconds)` function from `unistd.h`. Call this function between the `cout` statements.

Comment: That's completely true, however this will probably be simpler for him to understand.

Comment: That's not standard C++. There is a perfectly good sleep function in the standard library. Essentially, `this_thread::sleep_for( 2s );`.